# Is there any way to prevent closing nautilus with multiple tabs?

Tags: nautilus

Just like firefox, when you try to close it, a warning is raised that you need to confirm to close multiple tabs.

Is it possible for nautilus?

Comment: This is probably a feature that you need to [request them](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+filebug) to implement.